# SQLAlchemy bounds in between dates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following query :

```
query_news = sa.select([relaciones_laborales.c.PersonalPerId])
               .where(relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch.between(sa.bindparam('p1d'),sa.bindparam('p2d')))
```

If I'm correct, the bounds in a `BETWEEN` are not included e.g. range notation (p1d, p2d), and not [p1d, p2d].

Let's say I want to write a condition that represents the range [p1d, p2d) with the RelLabFch attribute greater or equal to p1d and less than p2d, I would need to explicitly write the condition as such:

```
query_news = sa.select([relaciones_laborales.c.PersonalPerId])
               .where(relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch.between(sa.bindparam('p1d'), sa.bindparam('p2d')) | relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch == sa.bindparam('p1d'))
```

Is there a simpler way of writing the above piece of code that represents `[p1d, p2d)`, which is the same as `>= p1d AND < p2d`?

Comment: Hi @Hernan Acosta. What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: If I remember correctly SQL BETWEEN is inclusive. A simple way would be to just `where((relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch >= sa.bindparam('p1d')) & (relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch < sa.bindparam('p2d')))`.

Comment: @Onel Harrison Im using sqlalchemy 1.0.13

Answer (score 2):

Using a SQL BETWEEN operator will evaluate ranges in an inclusive manner.

`BETWEEN 10 AND 20` is the same as [10, 20].

To write a simple query that represents [10, 20), you can do the following as suggested by [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4).

```
query_news = sa.select([relaciones_laborales.c.PersonalPerId])
               .where(relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch >= sa.bindparam('p1d') & \
                      relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabFch < sa.bindparam('p2d'))
```